# Error_csrf in edit user form when call Ajax function in ion_auth

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter-3, csrf-protection, ion-auth

I have error_csrf in edit user form when call function Ajax drop down for Country State & City.
I have the same error with:

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = FALSE;
```

And

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_token_name'] = 'csrf_test_name';
$config['csrf_cookie_name'] = 'csrf_cookie_name';
$config['csrf_expire'] = 7200;
$config['csrf_regenerate'] = TRUE;
$config['csrf_exclude_uris'] = array('dashboard/get_city/.*+','dashboard/get_city/[0-9]+');
```

When i submit the form of edit user i have this error "This form post did not pass our security checks." but only when i change drop-down of country who it call an Ajax function {dashboard/get_city/[0-9]+} to update a drop-down of list of city,
and when i don't change de drop-down of country and they are not a call to this Ajax function, the submit form is OK, and the user information are update

Thank you for your help.

Comment: That error message is not part of the codeigniter core. Some other security system has been included and is outputting that message.  The Codeigniter CSRF error is 'The action you have requested is not allowed.'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is csrf protection by ion auth, you just remove the line like this :

```
// do we have a valid request?
if ($this->_valid_csrf_nonce() === FALSE)
{
    show_error($this->lang->line('error_csrf'));
}
```

And just leave built-in Codeigniter CSRF protection to true :

```
$config['csrf_protection'] = TRUE;
```